# "z-index" on Bootstrap navbar and dropdown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, z-index

I have a problem in my navbar dropdown and cart dropdown.

I'm not sure how to fix this (I don't have solid knowledge about css `z-index`).

What I want is the shopping cart menu dropdown to stay on top of `navbar` menu dropdown.

I have changed the `z-index` on both dropdown menus and doesn`t work.
Thanks.

Here is the image:
[image: Shopping Cart Screenshot]

Here is the working jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/nmdh5vmv/2/

Comment: Your JSFiddle does not appear to reflect the image you've posted. When clicking the shopping cart, the popover just expands down - moving the rest of the content down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to asign to shopping cart menu dropdown a `z-index` bigger than `z-index` of navbar menu dropdown

```
.mega-dropdown-menu{
  z-index: 1;
}

.shopping-whist-bag{
  z-index: 2;
}
```